# ASP.NET remote debugging using Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

Im having issues getting this to work, maybe its not even possible?

I have a PUBLIC Server http://publicserver.com
I want to debug using my laptop from my home (for instance)

I run msvsmon.exe on the public server, it starts up fine.

On my local machine, i have my code open and in VS, i choose Debug->Attach
for Qualifier i enter publicserver.com, but it tells me it cannot find it

Questions:
1.) What port does remote debugging use?  If i port sniff i dont see msvsmon.exe opening any new port ... Does it use 4015 by default?

I dont think its a security thing, so please dont point me to the articles, i have followed them as much as i can, but they dont work for my scenerio (unless you find one i havent seen)

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: I just realized what you're doing after rereading your question. Remote Debugger works via RPC calls, similar to how MMC Remote Administration works. As far as I know, it isn't routable. You need to run this over a local network. You might try setting up a VPN connection to your remote server.

Comment: If the Windows Firewall is off, no firewall configuration is necessary... Firewall off, same result

Comment: I guess it is what it is, sounds like a limitation in my opinion, but then again i cannot assume this would be done very often.

Answer (score 1):

[How to: Manually Configure the Windows Vista Firewall for Remote Debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385831.aspx)

Comment: If the Windows Firewall is off, no firewall configuration is necessary... Firewall off, same result

Answer (score 0):

To debug an ASP.NET application remotely, turn windows authentication on remote debugger and add the user who is running visual studio. The server instance name is shown in this remote debugger window where u turn on windows authentication.
Now in VS, select attach to process and select transport level to default, in Qualifier give the full name of server (as seen in remote debugger options window) and attach to IIS process . Now break points will be hit 
If that does not work, then add the VS studio user in admin group on remote IIS machine.